# How to multiply in Java

Tags: java, android, numbers, multiplication

I am making a button that when pressed it multiplies a number by two but i keep getting an error saying invalid assignment operator and the red is underling the * which should mean multiply in java right?

```
mult.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ---->   counter  *2;
        display.setText("Your total is " + counter);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming there's no code before the counter * 2, it should either be counter = counter * 2; or counter *=2; You're not actually setting anything just by saying * 2 :P

Hopefully counter is a global variable so that it's actually saved outside of the method haha.

Answer (score 2):

`---->` is not an operator.

`counter*2` will multiply `counter` by 2 leaving `counter` as is.

Option 1:

`counter=counter*2;`

Option 2:

`counter*=2;`

Answer (score 0):

I think you `totally unintentionally` **missed the Assignment operator and the Lvalue on the Left Side to hold the resultant**...

Ok...see this..

```
int counter = 0;

mult.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        counter = counter * 2;     

        display.setText("Your total is " + counter);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mult.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int counter_output=counter  *2;
        display.setText("Your total is " + counter_output);
    }
    });
```

This would save the multiplication to an `int` variable, and then printing the variable with the saved multiplication would help to solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
// multiply without *
        int num1 = 3, num2 = 5;
        int mul = 0,j=0;
        while(j<num2)
        {
        for (int i = 0; i < num2; i++) {
            mul = mul + num1;
            j++;
        }
        System.out.println("Multiple "+mul);
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18851023)

Comment: are you from stack overflow team?this is an alternate way of solving